# How to get a column with count 0 in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the number of sales per petrol company. However I also want to include petrol companies that have made no sales but I cannot figure out how to do it. The `stations` table includes all the stations however `sales` only includes stations which actually had any sales.

This is how I am finding the number of sales per petrol station, but this doesnt include companies with 0 sales:

```
select stations.company,count(sales.sale) 
from stations 
   join sales on stations.id=sales.stationid 
group by stations.company;
```

My idea is to create a union with another query which just finds the companies with 0 sales but I don't know how to get a column with a 0 value in it. I tried to add `having count(sales.sale) = 0` but since the stations with no sales just don't appear in the sales table that doesn't work.

I have looked at similar stack overflow questions but they all seem to reference using a different type of join however I have tried using left/right outer/inner joins with no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is a great way to ask SQL related questions

Comment: Use a `left join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a minimum reproducible example so I can't be entirely certain, but seems like a case of needing a LEFT JOIN. Try the query below :

```
SELECT          stations.company, count(sales.sale) AS TotalSales
FROM            stations 
LEFT JOIN       sales ON stations.id=sales.stationid 
GROUP BY        stations.company
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using the join wrong. Would it also be possible to solve this problem using a subquery?

Comment: Yes, why not? But this will be more efficient.